# Adding dynamicly columns in c# - error

Tags: c#, datagridview

I try to run thid code

```
workersDVG.Columns.Add("WORKER", "worker");
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)workersDVG.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells["WORKER"].Value = 4;
workersDVG.Rows.Add(row);
```

But I get exeption because there is no column name "WORKER".
I'd be happy if someone could tell me where the problem is.
tnx.

Comment: WPF or winforms?

Comment: winforms. tnx!!!

Comment: Sorry, can't help you. Haven't worked with winforms in the last ~7 years.

Comment: You're adding a column and then trying to access a row in the grid...How are you binding your datasource to your grid that will generate the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Clone()` won't work because cloned row dows not contain column `Worker`.
Try like this:

```
workersDVG.Columns.Add("WORKER", "worker");
//add copy of first row (index 0)
int index = workersDVG.Rows.AddCopy(0);
//in var index you will find index of your newly added row.
//now add value of WORKER column in that new row
workersDVG.Rows[index].Cells["WORKER"].Value = 4;
```

Comment: Works! Thank you Nino!

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the documentation of [DataGridViewRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow(v=vs.110).aspx)  you can find the property `DataGridView` which:

> Gets the DataGridView control associated with this element

If you look into this in the debugger you will see that it is `null`:

[image]

So it will not be possible for the `row` to find any columns!
In addition it has the index of -1 because it is outside of the DataGridView.

Why not simply add the row below and change the value directly?! This works:

```
workersDVG.Columns.Add("WORKER", "worker");
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)workersDVG.Rows[0].Clone();    
workersDVG.Rows.Add(row);
workersDVG.Rows[1].Cells["WORKER"].Value = 4;
```